# How to fix loginButtons in Meteor 0.9 with Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

After adding the following to a Meteor 0.9 project:

```
standard-app-packages  1.0.0  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in yo...
bootstrap              1.0.0  Front-end framework from Twitter
iron:router            0.9.1  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
accounts-ui            1.0.0  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
accounts-password      1.0.0  Password support for accounts
```

and try to display `{{>loginButtons}}`:

```
<template name="header">
    <header class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="{{pathFor 'postsList'}}">Posts</a> 
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li>{{>loginButtons}}</li> 
                </ul>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </header>
</template>
```

the username/password dialog is shown partially outside the browser (same in Safari/Firefox/Chrome):

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

```
{{> loginButtons align="right"}}
```

to make it look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the position between **right** or **left**.

```
{{> loginButtons align="right"}}
```

However in your case, you must to fix the UI because the login form is misaligned with regard of the nav bar.

The fix is:

```
.navbar .nav {
        top:9px;
}
```